# Regex to catch string including ;(semi-colon)

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to get the assigning variable name and value from javascript code in HTML.

For example, there is html code:

```html
<html>
<head>~~</head>
<body>
  <div>contents</div>
  <script>
var value1 = 55;var value2= 27;
var value3 = 'T';var value4 = "FIT#$%SIZE";
var value5 = '{\"P00000WJ000E\":{\"stock_price\":\"0.00\",\"use_stock\":true,\"use_soldout\":\"T\",\"is_display\":\"T\",\"is_selling\":\"T\",\"option_price\":79000,\"option_name\":\"FIT#$%SIZE\",\"option_value\":\"NOBLE-44\",\"stock_number\":26,\"option_value_orginal\":[\"NOBLE\",\"44\"],\"use_stock_original\":\"T\",\"use_soldout_original\":\"T\",\"use_soldout_today_delivery\":\"F\",\"is_auto_soldout\":\"F\",\"is_mandatory\":\"T\",\"option_id\":\"000E\",\"is_reserve_stat\":\"N\",\"item_image_file\":null,\"origin_option_added_price\":\"0.00\"}}';
var value6 = '1';
var value7 = 'string;must-catch';
var value8 = 8;
var value9 = 'S';
var value10 = 'T';
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

expected things are:

```rb
result = {
  value1: 55,
  value2: 27,
  value3: 'T',
  value4: "FIT#$%SIZE",
  ...
}
```

In my environment, another parser tool cannot be used without Regex.
So trying to almost covered things like:

```regex
var\s(\w+)\s?\=\s?(\d+|\"[^;]*\"|\'[^;]*\')\s?\;
```

[image]

The result has appeared but, I also need to capture semicolon included string.
Any ideas?

Comment: You could add it to the capturing group after each match in the alternation https://regex101.com/r/UQAkq3/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird In this way, how to capture value4? https://regex101.com/r/oln4US/1

Comment: value 4 is captured right? https://regex101.com/r/UQAkq3/3

Comment: @Thefourthbird you right. But if value4's value is covered by two single quotes, it can't capture value4 right way. https://regex101.com/r/UQAkq3/4

Comment: I see you updated the question. Should it be like this? https://regex101.com/r/42wWRO/2

Comment: correct! but... https://regex101.com/r/42wWRO/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of not matching a semicolon using `[^;]*` you could match not a newline instead `[^\n']` and add the single or double quote to it `[^\n"]`

```
var\s(\w+)\s?\=\s?(\d+|\"[^\n"]*\"|\'[^\n']*\')\s?\;
                           ^^^         ^^^
```

If you do want to match a newline you can omit it from the [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) like `[^"]*` and `[^']*`.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DvmlDO/1)

Comment: I commented on above question, move it to here. Is there any way to avoid it? https://regex101.com/r/42wWRO/3

Comment: @Theforthbird any idea for it?

Comment: Try it like this `var\s(\w+)\s?\=\s?(\d+|\"(?:[^\n"]|\\")*\"|\'(?:[^\n']|\\')*\')\s?\;`  https://regex101.com/r/DvmlDO/5 using an alternation matching either not the quote or the escaped variant.

Comment: you brilliant..! save me.